# Download image from Express (Back-end) using React (Front-end)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, node-modules, mern

I have an image stored in Express server. I have been trying to download the image using the following method in a React component.

```
 <a href={my_image_url_from_state} download>Download Image</a>
```

But when i click on the 'Download Image' image is not downloaded. I see this error message:
[image]

I am able to display the same image in img tag, ie

```
<img src={my_image_url_from_state} />
```

that means nothing wrong with URL.

Do I need to make any changes in Express to download any files?

Comment: Can u open image url in a new tab?

Comment: @SureshPrajapati I hard-coded the image url. Image is opened in new tab

Comment: Also see this notes for using `download` attribute correctly
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#Attributes

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a function and invoke it on OnClick of the download button.

```
<button onClick={() => {download()}}>Download</button>
```

download function would be:

```
function download() {
var link = document.createElement('a');
link.href = 'images.jpg';
link.download = '<The URL of the image>';
document.body.appendChild(link);
link.click();
```

}

working code in reactJS class

```
    class App extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <img onClick={() => { download(); }} src="<The URL of the image>" />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

function download() {
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = 'images.jpg';
    link.download = '<The URL of the image>';
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
}
```

Comment: Can you please add a working code snippet so as to make this answer more helpful.

Comment: @SureshPrajapati I have edited my answer and added a React class

Comment: @AshishKirodian thanks for writing this answer bro. But,  this solution didn't work.  I figured out the root cause and fixed it after referring several articles. I will post solution for it. thanks anyways :)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up here because I was looking for a way to download an image in my React app from cloudinary and I found the snippet above as a useful starting point. I was getting the same error as [Darshn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3348373/darshn). I speculate that perhaps the reason it wasn't working is that the backend origin url was different than the client app's origin.

I then researched and found that the download attribute of an anchor element only works for same-origin URLs. See [The Anchor element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#Attributes)

I then found an article on Soumitra Roy Sarkar's [Roy Tutorials](https://www.roytuts.com/download-file-from-server-using-react/) that I was able to incorporate into a solution.

I determined that since I was pulling from a different origin I would need to fetch the image, convert it to a [Blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob), create a URL for it, attach the url to the anchor tag.

Since I already was using the Cloudinary React SDK I was able to add the cloudinary-core to my dependencies.

```
yarn add cloudinary-core
```

Then I imported it into my module

```
import cloudinary from 'cloudinary-core';
const cloudinaryCore = new cloudinary.Cloudinary({cloud_name: '<My Cloudinary Cloud Name>'});
```

My download function looks like:

```
function download({publicKey, name}) {

const downloadUrl = `${cloudinaryCore.url(publicKey)}.jpg`;
fetch(downloadUrl)
    .then((img) => img.blob())
    .then((blob) => {
        let url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        let link = document.createElement('a');
        link.href = url;
        link.download = name;
        link.click();
    })
}
```

The function can be called by an html element like this:

```
<button onClick={() => {download({publicKey: '12345', name: 'image.jpg'})}}>Download</button>
```